# A simple x86 disassembler open source for kernel use

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, processor, disassembly

I'm writing a kernel for educational purposes and I want to integrate a disassembler into my kernel.
Since I'm going to integrate it into the kernel I want it to be very small and simple,
i.e I only need it to receive a memory address and return the assembly instruction at that address.
I've looked for an open source that can do that but all I found is big libraries which are way too big and complicated.
I'm talking about a few (2-4) source code files that does not require a complicated installation/integration and that is very limited in it's abilities and only provide the very basic functionalities.
Does anybody know such an open source (for C of course)?

Comment: Disassemblers are large and complicated for complex architectures like the x86.

Comment: If licensing is an issue, [udis86](https://github.com/vmt/udis86) is a good option. Otherwise have a look at this [question and answers](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1817) over at RE.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You might have heard of the [radare2](http://radare.org/y/) project ([github](https://github.com/radare/radare2)). It includes [rasm](http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=rasm) which is a quite simple disassembler.

You can find their code in their [github repository](https://github.com/radare/radare2).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU gcc & binutils, you can just use objdump.  The way I usually use it is:

```
objdump -dSr my_file.o > my_file.s
```